# Haskell: Parse error in pattern: acc

Tags: haskell, parse-error

I found some Cloud Haskell Demos and I try to run it, but I get an error and I don't know why. The error looks like:

MasterSlave.hs:18:9: Parse error in pattern:acc

The code from MasterSlave.hs is:

```
module MasterSlave where

import Control.Monad
import Control.Distributed.Process
import Control.Distributed.Process.Closure
import PrimeFactors

slave :: (ProcessId, Integer) -> Process ()
slave (pid, n) = send pid (numPrimeFactors n)

remotable ['slave]

-- | Wait for n integers and sum them all up
sumIntegers :: Int -> Process Integer
sumIntegers = go 0
  where
    go :: Integer -> Int -> Process Integer
    go !acc 0 = return acc
    go !acc n = do
      m <- expect
      go (acc + m) (n - 1)

data SpawnStrategy = SpawnSyncWithReconnect
                   | SpawnSyncNoReconnect
                   | SpawnAsync
  deriving (Show, Read)

master :: Integer -> SpawnStrategy -> [NodeId] -> Process Integer
master n spawnStrategy slaves = do
  us <- getSelfPid

  -- Distribute 1 .. n amongst the slave processes
  spawnLocal $ case spawnStrategy of
    SpawnSyncWithReconnect ->
      forM_ (zip [1 .. n] (cycle slaves)) $ \(m, there) -> do
        them <- spawn there ($(mkClosure 'slave) (us, m))
        reconnect them
    SpawnSyncNoReconnect ->
      forM_ (zip [1 .. n] (cycle slaves)) $ \(m, there) -> do
        _them <- spawn there ($(mkClosure 'slave) (us, m))
        return ()
    SpawnAsync ->
      forM_ (zip [1 .. n] (cycle slaves)) $ \(m, there) -> do
        spawnAsync there ($(mkClosure 'slave) (us, m))
        _ <- expectTimeout 0 :: Process (Maybe DidSpawn)
        return ()

  -- Wait for the result
  sumIntegers (fromIntegral n)
```

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: Do you have `BangPatterns` enabled?

Comment: Also `remotable ['slave]` looks like it's probably supposed to be `TemplateHaskell`, do you have that turned on as well?

Comment: I think no. How can I set this flags?

Comment: put `{-# LANGUAGE ExtensionName #-}` at the top of your source file (before the module declaration) for each extension you want to enable.

Comment: Thank you a lot! This was the problem.

Comment: Great!  I'll type it up as an answer then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to have two language extensions enabled, `BangPatterns` and `TemplateHaskell`.  These can be enabled in two ways:

1. From the command line when compiling
2. In the source file the extension is being used (preferred)

To enable them at the command line, pass the flag `-XExtensionName` for each extension you need, so for your case you'd have `ghc -XTemplateHaskell -XBangPatterns source_file_name.hs`.

To enable them in source, use the `{-# LANGUAGE ExtensionName #-}` pragma at the top of the file:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
module MasterSlave where

...
```

---

Language extensions are a pretty big part of GHC Haskell.  There are some that are so common that they appear in most every real world application, like `OverloadedStrings` which allows you to use `Text` and `Bytestring` with `String` literal syntax, and `MultiParamTypeClasses` is indispensable for many of the more advanced libraries like `lens` and `mtl`.  Other common ones include the `Derive*` extensions like `DeriveFunctor`, `DeriveFoldable`, etc, that let the compiler derive more extensions than just the standard `Eq`, `Show`, `Read`, and co.

In your case, `BangPatterns` adds syntax for specifying extra strictness in function arguments and data type fields.  This helps reduce problems from implicit laziness, but it can also be used with too heavy a hand if you aren't careful.  `TemplateHaskell` enabled a lot of extra syntax for a templating/macro language built in to GHC.  Library authors can write template Haskell functions that take in a data type, expression, function name, or other constructs and build boilerplate code that doesn't need to be left to the user, but isn't easy or succinct to abstract otherwise.  The `lens` library uses it a lot, along with the Yesod web framework.